# Disable mouse when lid is closed

Tags: mouse, laptop, lid

How do I disable the mouse when the lid is closed? Sometimes my mouse gets moved around when carrying it, and it ends up clicking and moving around and creating a mess.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or Xorg?

Comment: I am using xorg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your computer to Suspend or Hibernate when lid is closed.  That will disable your mouse.

Comment: It does but I also would like to not suspend or hibernate when the lid is closed, or else I wouldn't have this problem